# Parsing a file with multiple line and replace the each first occurrence with Pipe

Tags: unix

Currently we have receiving a file, which is more like a name value pair. Each of the pair data is separated by pipe delimiter and Name and value pair is separated by space. I want to replace the space with Pipe inside the pipe delimited values.

I replace pipe to double code and tried using the below Perl Command line to add then replacing the space with the Pipe value. But it is add Pipe to each occurrence of the space.

```
perl -pe' s{("[^"]+")}{($x=$1)=~tr/ /|/;$x}ge'
```

Sample data:

```
|id 12345|code_value TTYE|Code_text Sample Data|Comments3 |  
|id 23456|code_value2 UHYZ|Code_text3 Second Line Text|Comments M D Test|   
|id 45677|code_value4 TEST DAT|Code_text Third line|Comments2 A D T Come|  
|id 78904|code_value |Code_text2 Done WIth Sample data|Comments |
```

Expected Result:

```
|id|12345|code_value|TTYE|Code_text|Sample Data|Comments3 |
|id|23456|code_value2|UHYZ|Code_text3|Second Line Text|Comments|M D Test|
|id|45677|code_value4|TEST DAT|Code_text|Third line|Comments2|A D T Come|
|id|78904|code_value |Code_text2|Done WIth Sample data|Comments |
```

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` script creates the output as shown in the question.

```
sed 's/\(|[^ ][^ ]*\) \([^|]\)/\1|\2/g' inputfile
```

From your expected output I assume the first space after a pipe should not be replaced with a pipe if it is followed by a pipe as in `|code_value |` or `|Comments3 |`.

Explanation:

`\(|[^ ][^ ]*\)` - 1st capturing group that contains a character which is not a space followed by 0 or more of the same
  - followed by a space
`\([^|]\)` - 2nd capturing group that contains a character which is not a pipe

`\1|\2` - replaced by group 1 followed by pipe and group 2

`/g` - replace all occurrences (**g**lobal)

Using the two grouped patterns before and after the space makes sure the script does not replace a space followed immediately by a pipe.

Edit: Depending on your `sed` you cpould replace the double `[^ ]` in the first group `\(|[^ ][^ ]*\)` with `\(|[^ ]+*\)` or other variants.

Comment: You can write the first group as `\(|[^ ]\+\)`.

Comment: @WalterA Depends on the `sed` implementation. `\+` (or `+`) is not part of POSIX BRE.

Comment: Thanks Bodo, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help